# pkgbuild: how to ignore version and overwrite?

Tags: macos, pkgbuild

I believe that my current build script creates an installer that only overwrites the existing binary if the version is newer, but I'd like to give my users the ability to go back to a previous version just in case.

My current build is:

```
pkgbuild  --analyze --root "./thing/" "name.plist" 

pkgbuild  --root "./thing/" \
     --component-plist "name.plist" \
     --identifier "com.me.pkg.name" \
     --version $VERSION \
     --install-location "/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components" \
     "name.pkg"
```

Do I simply remove the --version flag?

Comment: Package installers overwrite files by the same name regardless of the version.

Comment: I don't believe that's true. I had an issue where an installer I made was not overwriting a file and, after much debugging, it was because my version numbering was not correct.

Comment: That's ridiculous; If that were the case nobody would ever be able to roll back to an earlier version. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to remove the `--version` tag. That'll just make all packages have the same zero version. I've never tried this before but it appears there's a `BundleIsVersionChecked` variable that you can set to false within your plist. That "should" allow the installer to blindly install a package regardless of it's version.